# Order SliverList in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this widget:

```
body: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return _team(context, index);
                  }, childCount: Provider.of<Game>(context).teams.list.length),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Here I displays an array of objects (or list of maps) with a `int` property.

How can I order my array by this without modifying the variable itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a local variable and randomise it by using the below function and can use it.

```
List shuffle(List items) {
  var random = new Random();

  // Go through all elements.
  for (var i = items.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {

    // Pick a pseudorandom number according to the list length
    var n = random.nextInt(i + 1);

    var temp = items[i];
    items[i] = items[n];
    items[n] = temp;
  }

  return items;
}
```

Comment: sorry but I did not understand your question at all. What would I like to randomise it for?